# Kernel of inverse of the Möbius transformation

Tags: inverse, mobius-transformation

Given $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ the Möbius transformation. Calculate $ker(f^{-1}(id))$.

$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=w\implies w(cz+d)=az+b\implies z(wc-a)+wd-b=0$$$$\implies z=\frac{-wd+b}{wc-a}=f^{-1}(z)$$ The parameter matrix is then $$P=\begin{bmatrix}-d & b \\ c & -a \end{bmatrix}.$$
What is $f^{-1}(id)$?

Comment: what do you mean by kernel ?

Comment: ...and what do you mean by $\;f^{-1}(id)\;$ ? What is "id" here? Mobius transformations are maps from the complex to themselves, so what's "id" in the complex field?

Comment: Thats my problem, id=identity. In this case id=z?

Comment: @serge I've no idea....and what's kernel, in this context,  is also weird.

Comment: I think kernel of the parameter matrix. When id=z then the parameter matrix is the identity matrix and kernel is trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the actual question is the following.

> What is the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism#Image_and_kernel) 
>   $${\rm ker}(\Phi)~=~\left\{M\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})\mid \Phi(M) =  {\rm id}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\right\}, \qquad {\rm id}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(z)~:=~z, \qquad z~\in~\mathbb{P}^1, \tag{1}$$ 
>   of the [group homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) $$SL(2,\mathbb{C})~\ni ~M~=~\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr c & d \end{pmatrix} \quad\stackrel{\Phi}{\mapsto}\quad \Phi(M)~\in~{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1),\tag{2}$$
>   into the group ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ of [Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
>   $$ \Phi(M)(z)~=~\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \quad?\tag{3}$$

*Answer:* $${\rm ker}(\Phi)~=~\{\pm {\bf 1}_{2\times 2}\}, \qquad {\bf 1}_{2\times 2}~:=~ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} . \tag{4}$$

Comment: Do you mean with $1_{2\times 2}$ a matrix where all entries are 1?

Comment: @serge: I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, $ker(\Phi)=\{\Phi (M)(z)=0\}$, but $\Phi (1_{2\times 2})\not = 0$?

Comment: @serge: I updated the answer.